# Get foreign key value for queried object in Django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I've got a search query as follows:

```
ct = Classified.objects.filter(
    Q(name__icontains=q) |
    Q(subcategory__parent__type__icontains=q) |
    Q(address__area__icontains=q) |
    Q(subcategory__name__icontains=q)
).filter(active__icontains='yes').filter(address__city__name__exact=cit)
```

for the Classified model:

```
class Classified(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    phone_number = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=20, default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='dynamic/img/')
    NO = 'NO'
    YES = 'YES'
    APPROVAL = ((NO, 'no'), (YES, 'yes'))
    active = models.CharField(choices=APPROVAL, default=NO, max_length=3)
    verified = models.CharField(choices=APPROVAL, default=NO, max_length=3)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

where the Subcategory model is:

```
class Subcategory(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Categories, null=True, blank=True, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The Category table is not involved here so I've not included it.

In the view, I've to show a filter dropdown which is supposed to show a list of all unique subcategories for the results found in `ct`.

I tried two solutions:

```
getsubcat = Classified.objects.filter(
    Q(name__icontains=q) | 
    Q(subcategory__parent__type__icontains=q) | 
    Q(address__area__icontains=q) | 
    Q(subcategory__name__icontains=q)
).filter(active__icontains='yes').\
    filter(address__city__name__exact=cit).values('subcategory')
```

This gave me a list of all subcategories as: `{'subcategory': 1},{'subcategory':2}`. However this is not what I need as I need the exact `Subcategory.name` for the result in `ct`.

I tried the second method in the template as:

```
{% for subcat in result %}
   {{ subcat.subcategory.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

where `result` is passed from the views.py as `{ 'result': ct, }`. This however repeated the same subcategory `n` number of times where `n` is the number of results in `result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `values_list` to return only the `subcategory__name`.

Try something like

```
subcategories = ct.values_list('subcategory__name', flat=True).distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need subcategories, you should query subcategories.

```
Subcategory.objects.filter(classified__in=ct)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this give the same result as my second option?